# Facing error while installing ruby 2.6.5 in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, installation, rvm

When running command - rvm install ruby

This is the error I am getting

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/22.04/x86_64/ruby-3.0.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating systemThere has been an error while updating your system using `apt-get`.
It seems that there are some 404 Not Found errors for repositories listed in:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Make sure that all repositories are available from your system and verify your setup by running manually:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Make sure that it works correctly before proceeding with RVM.

If you are working from the GUI instead of the terminal, you might want to verify and fix broken
repositories using "Software & Updates" application.

........
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-3.0.0',
please read /home/rails-/.rvm/log/1699361525_ruby-3.0.0/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.

I tried to run sudo apt get-update but it didnt work

Comment: i highly recommend to use rbenv instead of rvm https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by checking the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-terminator-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
```

You can replace nano with your favorite editor.
This command will open a file, comment lines in the file, and save it.
Then run,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks this helped but then I got another error that is -
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /home/rails-/.rvm/log/1699420901_ruby-2.6.5/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.